# What is this wall fixture with a locking arm? How much weight is it rated for?

Tags: hanging, support

So, I have this thing attached to the concrete wall between mine and my neigbhor's balconies:

[image]

The arm has a slot in it's base that lets it slide around the nearest axis, and another slot that engages one of the other two axes. The arm can also be folded down.

The only use I have thought of for it is to hang a hammock from it, but I doubt that's the intended use, and if it's rated for that sort of weight.

I reckon I'll be asking something in this stack about this, so I might as well get this out of the way: What't the actual purpose of this thing, and is it likely to be strong enough to hold one end of a hammock?

Comment: It looks like a hanger for clothes

Comment: I agree with d.george.

Comment: The attachment screws will not hold a hammock.

Comment: Clothes line to string between the 2 balconies.